# How to access JSON field that doesn't have identifier

Tags: java, json

How could I access the #19 that is at the end of this JSON? Im using java 11 with GSON library but any library is okay or explanation.

**Some context**: usually I reference the field like `.get("id")` but that 19 is kind of the first time I see that and I know it is because of the circular reference that is in that JSON, we are using `@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")` [Annotation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jackson_annotations/jackson_annotations_jsonidentityinfo.htm) on our model classes to fix it. Also to mention the field "functionalityList" are the list of childs of a functionality, so in this example functionality with id 15 has the child with id 19. I appreciate any help or advise

```
[
    {
        "id": 15,
        "name": "Imprimir",
        "description": "Funcionalidad que permite imprimir",
        "functionalityList": [
            {
                "id": 19,
                "name": "Imprimir PDF",
                "description": "Funcionalidad que permite imprimir PDF",
                "functionalityList": [],
                "parentid": 15
            }
        ],
        "parentid": null
    },
    19
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a JSON Array, elements in an array are not supposed to have an identifier, something like

```
JsonArray arr = new JsonParser().parse(jsonString).getAsJsonArray();
```

you can then get the object (the first item in the array)

```
JsonObject object = arr.get(0).getAsJsonObject();
```

or the in at the int (the second item)

```
int id = arr.get(1).getAsInt();
```

Comment: Ahh right, its been a while I forgot there where json arrays, thanks dude